# QGIS Line Subdivide by distance

Tags: qgis, line, splitting

I know in QGIS you can subdivide a line, but is there a way you can type in a distance and the line will split according to this, with the last segment being smaller in length? If not I will try to script this in Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you write split in the Processing toolbox you will find a tool under GRASS named v.split.length:

[image]

Which will give you the option to define the desired distance to split the line:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I didn't have the latest version so I installed and now I see it. Works great.

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad it worked :)