# Splitting line with equal end parts

Tags: qgis-3, line, splitting

In QGIS 3.8.2 I would like to split line into equal segments.
The issue is, that `v.split` splits the line into the required segments, except the last segment.

I would like to split the line into equal segments, but with the first and the last segment to be equal length. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to split by line length or by number of segment parts?

Comment: By line length ...

Comment: Have you tried `v.split.length`? You can refer to this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297634/qgis-line-subdivide-by-distance

Comment: I cannot find tool v.split.length, I can see only v.split tool. But anyways, it split the line to equal segments, with the last one shorte. For example if the line is 55 m, and my goal is to have 10m segments, then it gives 5 segment of 10m and the last segment is 5m. I would like to get 5 segments of 10 m and 2 segments of 2.5 m.

Comment: I think that this will be probably possible only with a python script. The script description would look like this:
All lines to be split into 100m long segments;
If the last segment (X) is > than 50m => keep the value (=X);
If the last segment (X) is < than 50m => divide this segment by 2 (=X/2) =>  add up X/2 to the first and last 100m long segments (=100+X/2). Is there any simple way, how to write such script? I cannot find any guidline for noob coders. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that I want to divide line layer of following image in 5 equal segments.

[image]

In attributes table, it was calculated with geometry options of field calculator, total **line length** and **each equal segment length** (5 in total).

Afterward, I opened **v.split** tool and filled following options:

[image]

After click in Run, I got **Split by length** layer where it can be corroborated (after updating length field) that **v.split** worked as expected. In following image was selected third feature.

[image]

Comment: This only makes the seqments equal, not based on required segment sength. I wanna have segments for example 10m long and the first&last equal.